# XPath: preceding-sibling

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I wrote the following XPath and expected the previous `td` to be selected. However, it skips that one and selects the previous one + 1.

```
//td[@class='event_cell event_description']/preceding-sibling::td
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preceding-sibling::td` selects *all* of the preceding `td` sibling elements.

To select just the nearest one, use:

```
//td[@class='event_cell event_description']/preceding-sibling::td[1]
```

The numerical index here counts from nearest to farthest. So the nearest is `[1]`, second-nearest is `[2]`, and so on.